# "Unable to start debugging" - VS2010 ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I can launch debug session only once with VS2010 and ASP.NET MVC2. When I end the first session and try to launch another I can see...

"Unable to start debugging" - no other messages, I'm using Visual Studio Development Server instead of IIS, Windows 7 64-bit

I can add that few days ago I was working on Windows XP and everything was fine.

- I've tried running as admin (I thought there are any privileges issues) - no result
- checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee%28VS.71%29.aspx#vxtbshttpservererrorsthingstocheck (this page refers to IIS settings and I'm not using IIS)
- I'm not satisfied with manually attaching - VS2010 is expensive IDE, it HAS TO work in this situation

Does anyone have some conclusions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem auto-magically disappeared when:

1. I've turned off Debug > Edit and Continue option
2. Open vs2010 and run debug.
3. Turn off debug, shut down all launched WebServers (I had few of them for different services)
4. Close VS2010
5. Open VS2010.

After that everything works.

Comment: had the same problem manually upgrading from asp.net mvc 3 -> mvc 4 beta; closing vs and re-opening solved it. sigh.

Answer (score 12):

A simple restart of VS2010 sorted this for me

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem twice now and it occurs when I change my password for my computer. I have to go into IIS and change the password on the application pool to match my new password.

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this issue when updated AnkhSVN(I don't believe that updating could cause this problem but I didn't do anything else except code editing).

Closing Development Servers seems solve this issue until next time.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel